# How to test required init(coder:)?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xcode7.1beta

In my custom class `WLNetworkClient` I had to implement such method:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

I do not need to use that, but I would like to test this to make 100% code coverage. Do you know how to achieve this?

I tried following way with no success:

```
let nc = WLNetworkClient(coder: NSCoder())
XCTAssertNotNil(nc)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Production code:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    return nil
}
```

Test:

```
func testInitWithCoder() {
    let archiverData = NSMutableData()
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWithMutableData: archiverData)
    let someView = SomeView(coder: archiver)
    XCTAssertNil(someView)
}
```

Since the required initializer returns `nil` and does not use the coder, the above code can be simplified to:

```
func testInitWithCoder() {
    let someView = SomeView(coder: NSCoder())
    XCTAssertNil(someView)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in a slightly different situation. I'm calling super.init(coder: aDecoder) as the second line and it stops running on that line. No crash just doesn't finish the test.

Comment: Fails for me (Xcode 9.3, Swift 4.1): `test failure: testInitWithCoder() failed: failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "*** -decodeObjectForKey: only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSKeyedArchiver decodeObjectForKey:]!"
`

Comment: @Oliver, when I got that error, it was because I was feeding my initialiser a dedicated archiver in place of a dedicated DEarchiver... I should have created a new NSKeyedUnarchiver with the archiverData as init param.

Comment: The initializer `NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith:)` has been deprecated in iOS12. If you're getting that warning, you can replace the line with `let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(requiringSecureCoding: true)`

Comment: This wont work now, Fail with error `caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "*** -containsValueForKey: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class NSCoder: Create a concrete instance!"`

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887848/how-to-unit-test-this-custom-uitextfield-in-swift) is answer which should help you:

```
let cd = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: NSMutableData())
let c = CustomTextField(coder:cd)
```

Comment: Unfortunalety it stilll doesnt work: `*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is empty; did you forget to send -finishEncoding to the NSKeyedArchiver?`

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Rudolf Adamkovič ist still working with Swift 4:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    return nil
}

func testInitWithCoder() {
    // 1. Arrange
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: NSMutableData())

    // 2. Action
    let viewController = ViewController(coder: archiver)

    // 3. Assert
    XCTAssertNil(viewController)
}
```

Comment: `XCTAssertNil`? `XCTAssertNotNil` surely.

Comment: @Oliver Pearmain Given the current implementation returns nil, AssertNil is the right test (even if most of us are probably going to have NotNil)

Comment: NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: NSMutableData()) is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I combined Rudolf's answer with Liz's suggestion and ended with the following solution:

```
let viewController = SomeTableViewController(
    presenter: SomePresenterMock(),
    coder: NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: Data())) 

XCTAssert(viewController?.tableView.numberOfSections == 1)
```

The key here is to use `NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: Data())` as mock coder, otherwise the test crashes with `NSInvalidArgumentException`.

Answer (score 1):

I use improved Rudolf's Adamkovič answer:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func test_initWithCoder() {
    let object = SomeView()
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object)
    let coder = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data)
    let sut = SomeView(coder: coder)
    XCTAssertNotNil(sut)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that all the previous answers stopped working after Swift 5.

I managed to modify [@ChikabuZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66173036/12121668) answer and make it work like this:

```
func testInitWithCoder() {
    // Given
    let object = SomeView()
    let data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    let coder = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: data)

    // When
    let sut = SomeView(coder: coder)

    // Then
    XCTAssertNotNil(sut)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.x & macOS ≥ 10.14** - we don't want those pesky deprecation messages.

The nuts and bolts of `NSCoder`:

The `init(coder:)` expects an encoding of the same type, so it's safest to provide some matching base object, if it exists.

For example `NSView` *probably* won't like a coder containing `NSWindowController`.

---

For the question specifics, assuming: `WLNetworkClient` has a plain old init, we should create an instance of for coding.

We'll make a mock generator first, to avoid all that do / catch boilerplate.

```swift
// Helper function to create a mock NSCoder for testing init(coder:)
func mockCoder(for object: Any) -> NSCoder {
    do {
        // Archive the object to data
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(
            withRootObject: object,
            requiringSecureCoding: false)

        // Initialize NSKeyedUnarchiver as our NSCoder concrete instance.
        // Return it to our test code.
        return try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: data)
    } catch {

        // In production code, handle errors more gracefully 
        // (e.g. catch return nil and use a return type NSCoder?)
        fatalError("Error: Failed to create a mock NSCoder for \(object)")
    }
}
```

Use it in the test like this:

```
let coder: NSCoder = mockCoder(for: WLNetworkClient())

let sut = WLNetworkClient(coder: coder)

XCTAssertNotNil(sut)
```

No more nasty, red, coverage-missing, block. Just a nice, green, covered `init(coder:)`.